# Making a simple message box using C++/WinRT

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

I'm having trouble making a simple message dialog in C++/WinRT. Something as simple as "You clicked this: press ok to continue" nothing fancy. In the standard Windows API you can simply write `MessageBox()` and new popup will show up where you can click ok, and you can do somthing similiar in C++/CX with
`auto messageDialog = ref new Windows::UI::Popups::MessageDialog("You clicked on the button!"); messageDialog->ShowAsync();`

I've tried using `IMessageDialog` and `ContentDialog` classes with no success and can't seem to find a single example out there on how to do it without getting into writing Xaml code which for my perticular project seems unnecisary for something as simple as a message box. Maybe I'm just not setting them up right? But then again there are no examples on how to set it up in the first place (in C++). What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to use raw C++ or C++/WinRT?

Comment: @SimonMourier What's the difference? I am still pretty new to the idea of the Windows Runtime.

Comment: You can code WinRT using various languages (C/C++/Rust/.NET, etc.) provided you have the proper "bindings", whatever that means for the language in question. For C++, the easiest is C++/WinRT which uses modern C++ to make it easier (and is basically what Microsoft recommends for C++ against WinRT). It will actually look exactly like `Windows::UI::Popups::MessageDialog` etc. but without "exotic" notations like with C++/CX. You need a decent C++ compiler though.

Comment: Oh I see, yes I am using C++/WinRT.

Comment: This is not the case for all WinRT API, but as far as I know, you still need a CoreWindow around to have this MessageDialog API work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to form a simple message dialog using this:

```
winrt::hstring Title = L"Hello";
winrt::hstring Content = L"Some cool content!";
winrt::Windows::UI::Popups::MessageDialog dialog(Content, Title);
dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Make sure to also include `<winrt/Windows.UI.Core.h>` so you can get access to the UI library.
And here is the result:
[image]

Comment: For anyone in the future, if you can't find the `MessageDialog` in `winrt/Windows.UI.Core.h`, try the header:  `winrt/Windows.UI.Popups.h`